# How to type async function in TypeScript when its a void function

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

Here is my code:

```
async buildSomething(): any {
    const requestData = await request;
    requestData.forEach(i => this.table.push(i));
}
```

How I should type a void function, because it does something but It does not return anything.

In my case I used **any** but tslint shows me this:

**Type 'any' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.**

How should I achieve this?

Comment: is this unclear? why people put -1? dude, I just need some advice, thats all

Comment: Have you tried typing it as `void`?

Comment: yup, the same tslint message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All async functions return something: they return promises. So you don't want `void`, you want `Promise<void>`

```
async buildSomething(): Promise<void> {
    const requestData = await request;
    requestData.forEach(i => this.table.push(i));
}
```

Comment: yup, ur right, same as above, where I can learn about generics? every page has complex explanations, and Its hard for me trying to understand them

Comment: The basics are that it's an [thing] of [another thing]. e.g, "Array<string>" is an "array of strings". Generics let you describe how the type works in general (ie, they let you describe what "of" means in "array of strings"), and then when you use it, you can be more specific. In the case of a promise, the thing you get to be more specific about is what the promise will resolve to. `Promise<string>` is a promise that resolves to a string; `Promise<void>` is a promise that resolves to `void`

Answer (score 1):

The return type should be `Promise<void>`